# Websphere liberty controller cannot stop the member

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I created a cluster as explained in http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/tagt_wlp_configure_collective.html and http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_config_cluster.html.

I added adminCenter feature in my controller and tried stopping and starting a member in the cluster successfully.

However after I restart my controller and the member, i am not able to start or stop the members from the adminCenter. I am getting saying "Cannot connect to host xxx with the credentials provided".

I tried using collective updateHost to update the rpcUser and rpcUserPassword but with no luck.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The rpcUser has to be able to login directly to or ssh to the server on which the member server is running